# Autolayout UIButton and UILabel font size according to specific type of the iPhone size[NOT PROGRAMMATICALLY]

Tags: iphone, swift, user-interface, autolayout, font-size

I want to set different font size according to the IPhone size (4, 4.7 or 5.5 inch) [Here is one of the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120279/different-font-sizes-for-uibutton-and-uilabel-for-iphone-ipad)

But I want to ask is there is any way to auto resize UIButton / UILabel font size through interface builder without code? For example, how it works with holding ratio width - height of the UIsmth size?
If there is no way to do it as I described - what is the best practice to set font sizes. Should I do it as separate file for each UI element or it s better to do it in the appropriate UI elem subclass?
To concrete the question - I'm writing an web app for iPhone portrait only

Comment: It is unclear if the code in the link refers to the question or the answer. Maybe copy the code you are using here.

Comment: When you ask multiple questions you often get multiple answers making it hard to "pick" your accepted  answer. Please post one question at a time.

Comment: For this case, there's not an easy way to exert this level of control  through interface builder. You are looking at either creating a storyboard for each device type, which is unnecessarily complex, or defining Autoshrink font sizing on your labels

Comment: @zhon At this moment, I m using only storyboard to resize UI elements. I m able to scale any UI elements proportionally to the different screen size (4, 4.7, 5.5 inch). But I m not able to change font size of the UI elements, such as UIButton, UILabel and etc. In the answer I marked as " Here is one of the solution" exits solution to my problem but in this way I should write each font size to each screen size. And I m asking is there any way to do it automatically - proportionally

Comment: For example, button height is 100 and text takes 50 height of this on 4 inch. On 4.7 button's height will be 120, well, now the same text with another size will take 60 height. Can I somehow through constrain mechanism make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's possible you can use sizeClass for it.

Select the viewController wich you want to change the sizeFont,  then

HERE:

[image: SizeClass]

You select the sizeScreen you want **(it will appears blue where you see "any/any" )** and then select the textField, go to the

> Attributes inspector

and choose a new size clicking the plus button in the font section :

[image]

You will see something like this:

[image]

Select and change the size you want, It will work for you

Comment: In a more general case this would apply, however all three device types listed above, all fall into the same size class in portrait so for this question it offers no disambiguation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it' s not this case I want something like to choose iPhone 4 inch, iPhone 4.7 and iPhone 5.5 in portrait from identity inspector